# Performance counter NextValue returns same previous value

Tags: c#, performancecounter

```
File.Delete("D:\\filler.tmp"); // now %free space is 41
var freeSpaceCounter=new PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Free Space", "D:");
freeSpaceCounter.NextSample();
Console.WriteLine(freeSpaceCounter.NextValue()); // returns 41
freeSpaceCounter.Dispose();
freeSpaceCounter.Close();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Process p = Process.Start("fsutil", "file createnew d:\\filler.tmp 16000000000");
p.WaitForExit(); // now % free space is 1
Thread.Sleep(1000);
freeSpaceCounter = new PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Free Space", "D:");
freeSpaceCounter.NextSample();
Console.WriteLine(freeSpaceCounter.NextValue()); // returns 41
Console.WriteLine(freeSpaceCounter.NextValue()); // returns 41
Thread.Sleep(1000);
freeSpaceCounter.NextSample();
Console.WriteLine(freeSpaceCounter.NextValue()); // returns 41
Console.WriteLine(freeSpaceCounter.NextValue()); // returns 41
```

Why does it keep returning 41 when the actual value goes down to 1? How can I get current value multiple times?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT - Performance Counter details**

You will need to wait longer than 1000ms to see the change in free disk space using the `PerformanceCounter`.  The refresh rate for the `PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Free Space")` counter appears to be 300 seconds.  Calling `.NextValue()` repeatedly within this five minute interval will yield the same result as you are seeing.  This rate is based only on some testing I've done, so I can't speak for the consistency of this value across various platforms.

If you need a shorter sampling period, all I can suggest is that you close the application after taking your `NextValue` reading.  On reopening the app, you will see that the latest measure of disk space has been picked up by the new `PerformanceCounter` instance.  I don't believe `Close` and `Dispose` or even wrapping in `using`, and then creating a new instance had the same effect.  I did not dig too far into the details of this issue as I had the choice to use the following options.

**DriveInfo**

Alternatively, if you are not bound to the performance counter and are monitoring a local drive, you can use:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo("D:");
```

And `driveInfo.TotalFreeSpace` or other properties of the `DriveInfo` class.

**EDIT - WMI**

If you need to check remote machines also, you could use WMI.  Maybe the following will work for you.

```
System.Management.ManagementScope scope = 
    new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"\\remoteMachine\root\cimv2");

ObjectQuery query = 
    new ObjectQuery("SELECT Name, Freespace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3");

ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Drive: {0} -- Free Space: {1}", mo["Name"], mo["FreeSpace"]);
}
```

Comment: The code I have posted has similar behavior on local as well as remote machine. I need to query for free disk space on a remote machine so I cannot use DriveInfo class.

Comment: Must you use PerformanceCounters though?  How about WMI instead?

Comment: Revised answer on my experience with the PerformanceCounter and logical disk space. Hopefully that gives you something to work with.